# Go modules: How do you lock in a specific version that won't get overridden with `go get -u`?

Tags: go

If I specify a specific branch/version using `go get github.com/org/package@sha_or_branch` it will update accordingly. But if I run `go get -u` afterwards it gets overridden with any newer version.

Is there any way to lock it in so it doesn't change when doing a `go get -u`?

Comment: This is a strange question as the whole point of `go get -u` is to update a dependency to the given (or latest) version. You prevent go get -u from doing what it should do by not doing go get -u.

Comment: `go get -u` updates all dependencies. That should explain the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no way to do this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies) currently.

You can only specify if want to use the defined versions of the transitive dependencies of the packages you directly import or allow using a newer minor or patch version.